# Problemas para añadir y modificar Marcas en Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop1.7

Tengo un problema para añadir o modificar marcas(brands), el error que me sale es el siguiente:
"Se ha producido un error inesperado.[PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Domain\Manufacturer\Exception\ManufacturerException código 0]"
Este error me sale cuando le doy al botón de guardar la version de prestashop que tengo es  1.7.8.9 y la version de PHP es la 7.4.33

He probado revisando los modulos del Manufacturer del core por is fuera un problema con el update de versión, pero la verdad es que no veo nada.
Cualquier idea será bienvenida.